# App Links doesn't works well with a good assetlinks.json

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, applinks

The Android app link is not working. I lost 5 days of sleep over this, from Monday to today .

### What I did

1. I uploaded the `assetlinks.json` to my host, `gifthub.kr`, and it is accessible via https://gifthub.kr/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

   - There are three fingerprints. First one is from Play Console, second one is from `debug.keystore`, and the last one is from my upload keystore file.
   - The `Content-Type` of `assetlinks.json` is `application/json`
2. Then, I install my app through the `flutter run` command, and when I open `https://gifthub.kr/giftcards/deeplink` through Chrome, I was not directed to my app.
3. I searched and found that the app link doesn't work properly in debug mode. So I built it in release mode via `flutter build apk` and installed it via Firebase Distribution on real device. However, when I tried to link the app in the same way afterwards, it didn't work.
4. I searched and searched and searched. And find a command to see if my address was linked to my app. And my app opened on my phone, not in Chrome or any other browser. It was my application.

```bash
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://gifthub.kr/giftcards/deeplink"
```

### So I think

- I registered `assetlinks.json` coreectly via web deployment (As step 1)
- My address is associated with the app correctly (As step 4)

> ### But Why are the app link not work!

### My files

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
    android:value="true" />
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="gifthub.kr" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/giftcards/deeplink" />
</intent-filter>
```

---

`/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

```json
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "org.swmaestro.repl.GiftHub",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "CA:40:66:B3:4B:76:59:78:5F:32:7E:21:93:28:A5:76:F5:AF:E0:D6:15:6A:3B:6D:C0:08:35:56:3D:DC:D9:D7",
                "F3:92:4F:BA:47:C3:20:0E:35:87:C5:3A:70:1C:6D:6E:C2:E5:31:1B:CE:C5:08:B5:44:44:29:0A:27:26:C0:88",
                "E0:17:91:BD:A0:E7:23:F5:46:FC:62:03:4E:06:4A:CF:2A:9E:A7:53:40:BF:18:FC:15:EA:58:2D:80:E5:C2:C2"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

### My checklists

##### **Check Digital Asset Links Validation**: Is `assetlinks.json` correctly placed and accessible?

```bash
curl -v https://gifthub.kr/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

```
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Sat, 11 Nov 2023 07:47:39 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 633
< accept-ranges: bytes
< cache-control: public, max-age=0
< last-modified: Thu, 09 Nov 2023 09:45:13 GMT
< vary: Accept-Encoding
<
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "org.swmaestro.repl.GiftHub",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "CA:40:66:B3:4B:76:59:78:5F:32:7E:21:93:28:A5:76:F5:AF:E0:D6:15:6A:3B:6D:C0:08:35:56:3D:DC:D9:D7",
                "F3:92:4F:BA:47:C3:20:0E:35:87:C5:3A:70:1C:6D:6E:C2:E5:31:1B:CE:C5:08:B5:44:44:29:0A:27:26:C0:88",
                "E0:17:91:BD:A0:E7:23:F5:46:FC:62:03:4E:06:4A:CF:2A:9E:A7:53:40:BF:18:FC:15:EA:58:2D:80:E5:C2:C2"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

##### **Review Android App Links Documentation**: Do intent filters and metadata configurations set correctly in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Flutter Documentation says

> 1. Open the Flutter project with VS Code or Android Studio.
> 2. Navigate to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file.
> 3. Add the following metadata tag and intent filter inside the  tag with .MainActivity.
>
> Replace example.com with your own web domain.
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
> <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
>     <data android:scheme="https" />
> </intent-filter>
> ```

And my `meta-data` and `intent-filter` are correctly placed in `.MainActivity`.

##### **Check for Multiple Intent Filters**: Check that there is only one deep link, so that it is not overshadowed by another filter that catches the URLs.

I have 5 intent filters, and there is only one for the `android.intent.action.VIEW` action.

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="gifthub.kr" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/giftcards/.*/deeplink" />
</intent-filter>
```

##### **Test with App Links Assistant**: Try App Links Assistant to test the association and troubleshoot this issue.

[image: Result of checking URL mapping]

App Links Assistant says my URL maps to `.MainActivity` correctly

##### **Verify MIME Type**: The `assetlinks.json` has correct MIME type `application/json`?

According to the `curl` result, the content type of `assetlinks.json` is `application/json`.